# Changing/Setting Site Language in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, language, language-pack

I'm trying to set the language of a SharePoint site to Swedish (or, create a new site *in* Swedish).  I have found a few articles online giving mixed answers. Here is what I've tried:

> On a site, go to Site Settings > Site Administration > Language Settings

**Problem:** There is no Language Settings link under Site Admin

> When you create a new site from Central Admin, select the language from the Language field above where you select the template.

**Problem:** There is no Language field above Select a template.

> Add the Swedish language pack from Control Panel > Language

This didn't change anything.

> Move Swedish to the top so that it is the default, system language.

This didn't change anything.

I'm at a loss... there has to be some way to change the language of a site.  Does anyone have any advice on what I can try?

Comment: Have you *Language Packs for SharePoint Server 2013* (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=37140) installed?

Answer (score 2):

**First,** You should be aware of `Creating a new Site based on a Specific Language` is not dependent on the System Language.

**Second,** To be able to `Create a new site based on a specific language` ([Swedish](https://www.microsoft.com/sv-SE/download/details.aspx?id=37140)), you should install its corresponding Language Pack.

**Third,** What's the Language Pack?

**Language packs** enable creation of sites and site collections in multiple languages without requiring separate installations of SharePoint Server 2013.

> **Note:** Multiple language packs can be installed on the same server.

**Fourth,** From where can I download the `Svenska` Language Pack for SharePoint 2013?

You can download `Svenska` Language Pack for SharePoint 2013 from [Språkpaket för SharePoint Server 2013 – [Svenska]](https://www.microsoft.com/sv-SE/download/details.aspx?id=37140)

**Fifth,** How can I install the SharePoint Language Pack?

- After downloading your preferred SharePoint Language Pack,

  - If you have a `standalone SharePoint server`, Just install the downloaded Language Pack, Then Run the SharePoint Configuration Wizard.
  - If you have `Complete farm`,

    - So you should Install the downloaded Language Pack on **All** SharePoint Servers within the farm.
    - Then Run the **SharePoint Configuration Wizard** on **All** SharePoint Servers cross the farm, started from the server that hosts the Central Administration.

> **Note:** If you do not run the SharePoint Products and Technologies Configuration Wizard after you install a language pack, the language
>   pack will not be installed properly.

**Finally,** To change the `SharePoint Language Settings`

- Open your site with `Internet Explorer` > Go to Site Settings > Site Administration > Language settings.
- Check your Alternate language > Click on Ok.
- From `Internet Explorer` Menu > Tools > Internet Options > General Tab > Click on Language Button below `appearance` section.
- Click on Set Language preferences > and Move your Alternate language Up.

[image]